# Send Multicast UDP in a packaged Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, udp, google-chrome-app, multicast

I am trying to send a simple udp multicast packet to 255.255.255.255 inside of a chrome app. I am able to get regular udp packets to send, but as soon as I try a broadcast address I get 'Unchecked runtime.lastError while running sockets.udp.send: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED'

My manifest looks like

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "UDP Multicast",
  "description": "udp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon.png" },
  "sockets": {
    "udp": {
      "send": "*",
      "bind": "*"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    {"socket": ["udp-bind", "udp-send-to"]}
  ]
}
```

and my background.js

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  // chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
  //   'bounds': {
  //     'width': 400,
  //     'height': 500
  //   }
  // });

  chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
    var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(6);
    var buffer = new Uint16Array(arrayBuffer);
    buffer[0] = 0x2e
    buffer[1] = 0x2c
    buffer[2] = 0x3a
    buffer[3] = 0x01
    buffer[4] = 0x00
    buffer[5] = 0x00
    chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, "0.0.0.0", 0, function(result) {
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, buffer.buffer, '255.255.255.255', 4201, function(sendInfo) {
        console.log("sent ", sendInfo.bytesSent);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add the debug like "if (sendInfo.resultCode < 0) {
                console.log("Error listening: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }" in "chrome.sockets.udp.send()"

Comment: The error code I receive is -10, which appears to be the same as net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: It seems broadcast (255.255.255.255) not to apply to the new API. Have you tried the old API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket? I think it should apply to the newer "chrome.sockets.udp".

Comment: I receive the same -10 error code using the old api.

Comment: @TraeRobrock I am having the same issue, have you ever figured out the problem?